# JButton is only appearing on MouseOver

Tags: java, graphics, jbutton

I've tried multiple things but I can't seem to figure out how to get my *JButton* over the background graphics. Does anybody know how I can paint over this background and have my button stay there? I would paste the code here but It would get a little messy, so heres some pastebin links!

**Main** class: http://pastebin.com/DvVfCU03

**MenuPanel** class: http://pastebin.com/uht8cabX

Here's a copy of the main class just in-case:

```
public class Main
{
    final static JFrame window = new JFrame();
    final static ImageIcon imageIconOne = new ImageIcon(getConnectImage());
    final static JButton connectB = new JButton(imageIconOne);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setContentPane(new MenuPanel());
        window.addKeyListener(new MenuPanel());
        window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1024, 640));
        window.pack();
        window.setTitle("Realm of Pixels");
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.add(connectB);
    }

    public static Image getConnectImage()
    {
        Image connectImage = null;

        try
        {
            connectImage = ImageIO.read(new File("Resources/Buttons/Connect.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return connectImage;
    }

    public static JFrame getWindow()
    {
        return window;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the code in your question. That way others can more easily relate to it immediately, and it won't be worthless if the links break.

Comment: @Ondkloss Just added the main class just in-case.

Comment: add button before pack and set visible to frame

Comment: @peeskillet Just did, made no difference whats-so-ever

Comment: Then post a _simplified_ runnable example that replicates the problem. We can run this code because of missing custom classes and resource files

Comment: Also see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). You should run all your swing apps on the EventDispatchThread

Comment: @peeskillet To run an example just copy my two classes, drop them into a project. Replace the Resources/etc/etc with any images you want in the project :)

Answer (score 0):

I maybe wrong but,

shouldn't you be making the button visible too? Something like...

`connectDB.setVisible(true);`

Or to see if the button has been added to the window you could temporarily set the button to opaque.